# Kivy Android app crashes when changing BoxLayout sizes and scrolling at the same time?

Tags: python, kivy, multi-touch

I have developed an Android app using the Python framework Kivy. The layout is divided in two parts using BoxLayouts ("upper_space" and "lower_space"). As seen on the following screenshot (sorry for the huge size):

[image]

#### User Scenario:

**The user scrolls in the "lower_space" area and hits the button on the "upper_space" area at the same time (multitouch). The app crashes.**

The button changes both BoxLayout's height. How can we prevent the app from crashing in the described user scenario and maybe even without having to change my whole layout?

The content of the "lower_space" area should be scrollable and in this example it is a GridLayout including SmartTiles, but it could also be anything else like a long BoxLayout with multiple Buttons, Labels, Images, etc. The content of the "upper_space" should be something static (non-scrollable) like an image or text with the button that changes both BoxLayout's height.

Here is my code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            id: upper_space
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: 0.3
            
            BoxLayout:
                id: title_bar
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint_y: 0.3
                    
                MDIconButton:
                    icon: 'delete'
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    on_release:
                        app.size_hint_y_layouts('upper_space', 0, 'lower_space', 1)
                        
            BoxLayout:
                id: preview_widget
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: 0.8
                
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Some Label'
                    halign: 'center'
        
        BoxLayout:
            id: lower_space
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: 0.7
            
            ScrollView:    
                id: somescroll
                GridLayout:
                    id: somegrid
                    cols: 2
                    row_default_height:
                        (self.width - self.cols*self.spacing[0])/self.cols
                    row_force_default: True
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                
                    SmartTileWithLabel:
                        box_color: [0.2,0.2,0,1]
                        text: "Tile1"
                        font_style: 'H3'
                        
                    SmartTileWithLabel:
                        box_color: [0.2,0.2,0,1]
                        text: "Tile2"
                        font_style: 'H3'
                
                    SmartTileWithLabel:
                        box_color: [0.2,0.2,0,1]
                        text: "Tile3"
                        font_style: 'H3'
                
                    SmartTileWithLabel:
                        box_color: [0.2,0.2,0,1]
                        text: "Tile4"
                        font_style: 'H3'
                        
                    SmartTileWithLabel:
                        box_color: [0.2,0.2,0,1]
                        text: "Tile5"
                        font_style: 'H3'
'''

class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return screen
    
    def size_hint_y_layouts(self, layout1, size_hint_y1, layout2, size_hint_y2):
        self.root.ids[layout1].size_hint_y = size_hint_y1
        self.root.ids[layout2].size_hint_y = size_hint_y2
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

I have thought about multiple options, but maybe you have a better idea?

#### Idea 1: prevent the usage of multitouch

As multitouch function is not so important in my app, I could disable it completely. Using the following code results into strange behaviour on the Android phone (scrolling not working). I guess this is because the code is for a PC platform. Is there a modified version for smartphone touchscreens?

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
```

#### Idea 2: Disabling the ScrollView or changing the do_scroll property to False

Both did not solve my problem unfortunately as the app keeps crashing in the described user scenario. Notice that I have to set the do_scroll property to True again after changing the BoxLayout's height and I have to enable the ScrollView again as the "lower_space" area could have a lot of content (it has to be scrollable!). Here is some code snippets that I have tried out (only the button's event has changed, the remaining code is identical):

```
MDIconButton:
    icon: 'delete'
    size_hint_x: 1
    on_release:
        root.ids['somescroll'].do_scroll = False
        app.size_hint_y_layouts('upper_space', 0, 'lower_space', 1)
        root.ids['somescroll'].do_scroll = True
```

And here:

```
MDIconButton:
    icon: 'delete'
    size_hint_x: 1
    on_release:
        root.ids['somescroll'].disabled = True
        app.size_hint_y_layouts('upper_space', 0, 'lower_space', 1)
        root.ids['somescroll'].disabled = False
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Update 08/03/2021:** here is a small part of the log:

```
03-08 10:45:15.991 18259  4607 I python  :  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
03-08 10:45:15.991 18259  4607 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: Please attach the log

Comment: Thanks for your comment! As debugging runs without any problems, I have looked into the log when deploying (USB debugging on Android device) at the moment of crashing. Only the part of the log after the crashing is actually huge. I am not sure how to make it smaller and more specific to my problem. In `the buildozer.spec` file I use `android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D`. I have now added the last two lines of the log to show that the problem seems to be a Python `RecursionError`. If this is not helpful, please tell me how to insert my log here on Stackoverflow (max. 30k characters allowed)?

Comment: attach link or txt file

Comment: your code works fine for me, use `kivy==2.0.0` or master and `kivymd` from github, and latest buildozer version `pip install --user https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/archive/master.zip`

Comment: Did you press the button on top while scrolling and release it while you are still scrolling on bottom (lower space) on an Android device? Because that is when the app crashes.